# How does ambipolar transport work?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

In my introductory semiconductor physics class, I learned that "excess holes and electrons move together in the presence of an applied electric field because of the development of an internal electric field that provides a force attracting the excess holes and electrons". I do understand that the applied electric field will lead to a charge separation and the charge separation will lead to the development of an internal electric field causing an attraction between holes and electrons. However, I do not understand how holes and electrons can move **together**. Unless the internal and applied electric fields have the same magnitude, shouldn't holes and electrons have opposite net forces and still move in opposite directions although their acceleration and speed may decrease due to the presence of internal electric field?

Moreover, even under the assumption that they do move together, how do they drift in an applied electric field while the packet of a hole and an electron pair would have no net charge?

Comment: ‘Together’ has multiple meanings. One is, in essence, ‘side-by-side’, the other is ‘coming together’. That sentence needs more context to determine which meaning is meant.

Comment: Sorry but 'together' is literally what the textbook and my lecture note say.

Comment: I understand. More context around that one sentence will help untangle which meaning is appropriate.